# ajax/php autocomplete issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

i'm new to pdo and json. I want to make an autocomplete searching by username and also displaying pic next to name. The issue i have is that my script is not displaying pic next to name but it makes it part of autocomplete, i mean it displays if it matches the letters from the search box. Sorry if my english is bad.Here is my sql script:

```
include("configPDO.php");
// Query to get the usable suggestions
    $likeString = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';

// We Will prepare SQL Query
    $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT   username,avatar,id FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE :likeString");
// bind parameters, Named parameters always start with colon(:)
   $STM->bindParam(':likeString', $likeString);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
    $STM->execute();
// we will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results
    $STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
    $Category_array = array();
    foreach($STMrecords as $row)
        {
           $result = $row[0].$row[1];

           array_push($Category_array, $result);    
        }

         $json = json_encode($Category_array);
    echo $json;
```

this is my ajax code using jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Get_Auto1.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
    $('#searchg').autocomplete(
    {
    source: data,
    minLength: 1    
    });
    }
          });

});
</script>
```

Thnx in advance.

I managed to make it displaying the avatar next to each result but id doesnt show the image itself just the url ex:"http://twingoo.ro/images/twingoo_logo.png", i also tryed with img src. I modified this line of code: `$result = $row[0].$row[1];`

here is the link of the demo: [demo link](http://twingoo.ro/auto/demo.php)

Comment: Check the url of the image or the tag `img` you create - if any. We need more info, this code is not enough.

Comment: the query or the array is not correct, cause it doesnt put the img from the database next to username after search

Comment: But dude, think. How do we know whats wrong if we don't know your data, the requests response and stuff? It's impossible to tell. Can you provide more information? If not, delete this cause nobody will be able to help you.